# Why does Maven 3.3 not include 'javax.inject' but Maven 3.2 does?

Tags: java, maven, maven-3, dagger-2

My Maven build fails when using Maven 3.3.1 but is successful with Maven 3.2.2.

So far I have run `/path/to/3.3.1/mvn clean compile -X` and compared the output to the one produced by `/path/to/3.2.2/mvn clean compile -X`.

There was exactly *one* difference in the following block inside the `maven-compiler-plugin / default-compile` phase:

```
[DEBUG] Populating class realm plugin>org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-compiler-plugin:3.2
[DEBUG]   Included: org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-compiler-plugin:jar:3.2
[DEBUG]   Included: com.google.dagger:dagger-compiler:jar:2.0
[DEBUG]   Included: com.google.dagger:dagger:jar:2.0
[DEBUG]   Included: com.google.dagger:dagger-producers:jar:2.0-beta
[DEBUG]   Included: com.google.guava:guava:jar:18.0
...
```

**Difference:** While Maven 3.2.2 printed `[DEBUG]   Included: javax.inject:javax.inject:jar:1`, it is missing for Maven 3.3.1.

I don't know if this helps, but this is my effective build plugin:

```
<plugin>
    <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
    <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>3.2</version> <!-- 3.3 respectively -->
    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.google.dagger</groupId>
            <artifactId>dagger-compiler</artifactId>
            <version>2.0</version>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>
    <configuration>
        <source>1.8</source>
        <target>1.8</target>
        <!-- workaround for http://jira.codehaus.org/browse/MCOMPILER-202 -->
        <forceJavacCompilerUse>true</forceJavacCompilerUse>
    </configuration>
</plugin>
```

What I don't understand: What exactly does the "Populating class realm plugin" do? Why is a jar missing, even though it has been identified as a dependency by both maven versions?

Edit: Build fails with this exception:

```
[ERROR] Failed to execute goal org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-compiler-plugin:3.2:compile (default-compile) on project ui: Compilation failure -> [Help 1]
org.apache.maven.lifecycle.LifecycleExecutionException: Failed to execute goal org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-compiler-plugin:3.2:compile (default-compile) on project ui: Compilation failure
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute(MojoExecutor.java:212)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute(MojoExecutor.java:153)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute(MojoExecutor.java:145)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleModuleBuilder.buildProject(LifecycleModuleBuilder.java:116)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleModuleBuilder.buildProject(LifecycleModuleBuilder.java:80)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.builder.singlethreaded.SingleThreadedBuilder.build(SingleThreadedBuilder.java:51)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleStarter.execute(LifecycleStarter.java:128)
    at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.doExecute(DefaultMaven.java:307)
    at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.doExecute(DefaultMaven.java:193)
    at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.execute(DefaultMaven.java:106)
    at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.execute(MavenCli.java:862)
    at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.doMain(MavenCli.java:286)
    at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.main(MavenCli.java:197)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:497)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.launchEnhanced(Launcher.java:289)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.launch(Launcher.java:229)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.mainWithExitCode(Launcher.java:415)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.main(Launcher.java:356)
Caused by: org.apache.maven.plugin.compiler.CompilationFailureException: Compilation failure
    at org.apache.maven.plugin.compiler.AbstractCompilerMojo.execute(AbstractCompilerMojo.java:913)
    at org.apache.maven.plugin.compiler.CompilerMojo.execute(CompilerMojo.java:129)
    at org.apache.maven.plugin.DefaultBuildPluginManager.executeMojo(DefaultBuildPluginManager.java:134)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute(MojoExecutor.java:208)
    ... 20 more
```

A minimal example project is available on [GitHub](https://github.com/totalvoidness/daggerfx).
The full output of the failing command is available [here](https://gist.github.com/totalvoidness/23b84bd586334aaf9cd0).

Comment: Would be helpful if you can state what the actual build error is. There's nothing in your question to suggest the `javax.inject` difference is the cause of your build failure.

Comment: added exception, even though it is just a generic compilation error stack trace

Answer (score 3):

The problem is not with the version of maven-compiler-plugin.
When you use the option **forceJavacCompilerUse** it would basically use javax.tool API implementation within your JDK.
Since you are using **dagger-compiler**,  which is intern dependent on **javax.inject**, it should get pulled.

You can try adding **[provided] scope** for your dagger-compiler plugin dependency, this way you would be locking all the transitive dependencies.

Also make sure that you have added **dagger**
 dependency in your runtime dependencies.

Please provide the some more details of exception-stack-trace and other related areas of your pom that would help visitors to narrow-down the problem and guide you quick!

Comment: I added both a minimal project to reproduce this problem as well as the full log file. The stack trace is already complete. Adding a `dagger-compiler` dependency with provided scope doesn't change anything :-/

Comment: Adding dagger-compiler with provided scope _and_ using javax.tools compiler solved this problem. I just pushed my updated pom.xml to the GitHub project mentioned in my question. It is now working, but I don't understand why it doesn't work as a build plugin dependency. If you add something about the javax.tools vs. javac compiler and how plugin dependencies differ from project dependencies, I'll accept this answer.

Comment: Hi Sebastian, I have cloned your sample project and tried building on my machine and it was building fine. This is the [pom](https://github.com/iNithya/daggerfx/blob/master/pom.xml) I used. Here is the  [partial debug log](https://gist.github.com/iNithya/6ccb1a387b32d3946040) and [info log](https://gist.github.com/iNithya/0ce4c1c4878a81072c1a).

Comment: You have been using Maven 3.2.1, which didn't cause any problems on my machine either. Try Maven 3.3 and it should fail.